# Calculate percentage between two columns in SQL Query as another column per day

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate the daily % split of the `No_of_daily_installs`.

Question:

Could someone explain how can I add a new column that represents the daily plit % of the `No_of_daily_installs` per `LAT_type` as %?

What I have now:

```
|-----------|-------------------|--------------------|-----------------------|
|Insall_Date|Lat_type           |No_of_daily_installs| RunningTotal_Installs |
|*---------*|*-----------------*|*------------------*|*---------------------*|
|2021-06-30 |Ad Tracking Enabled|   613              |21345                  |
|2021-06-30 |Limit Ad Tracking  |  3723              |74273                  |
|2021-06-29 |Limit Ad Tracking  |  3553              |70550                  |
|2021-06-29 |Ad Tracking Enabled|   480              |20732                  |
|2021-06-28 |Limit Ad Tracking  |  2869              |66997                  |
|2021-06-28 |Ad Tracking Enabled|   375              |20252                  |
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
|-----------|-------------------|--------------------|--------------|-----------------------
|Insall_Date|Lat_type           |No_of_daily_installs|%_of_daily_LAT| RunningTotal_Installs |
|*---------*|*-----------------*|*------------------*|*------------*|*---------------------*|
|2021-06-30 |Ad Tracking Enabled|   613              |0.15          |21345                  |
|2021-06-30 |Limit Ad Tracking  |  3723              |0.85          |74273                  |
|2021-06-29 |Limit Ad Tracking  |  3553              |0.80          |70550                  |
|2021-06-29 |Ad Tracking Enabled|   480              |0.20          |20732                  |
|2021-06-28 |Limit Ad Tracking  |  2869              |0.85          |66997                  |
|2021-06-28 |Ad Tracking Enabled|   375              |0.15          |20252                  |
```

My code so far:

```
WITH "Adtracking" (
    "Install_Date",
    "Lat_type",
    "No_of_daily_installs"
) AS (
    SELECT
        to_date("created_at") date_install,
        CASE WHEN "tracking_limited" = '1' THEN
            'Limit Ad Tracking'
        ELSE
            'Ad Tracking Enabled'
        END AS "Ad Tracking",
        count("tracking_limited") AS "number_of_occurences"
    FROM
        TEMP_DB.DATA_LAKE.ADJUST_CSV_DATA
    WHERE
        TRUE
        AND "platform" = 'mobile_app'
        AND "activity_kind" = 'install'
        AND "os_name" = 'ios'
    GROUP BY
        1,
        2
    ORDER BY
        1,
        2
)
SELECT
    "Install_Date",
    "Lat_type",
    "No_of_daily_installs",
    SUM("No_of_daily_installs") OVER (PARTITION BY "Lat_type" ORDER BY "Install_Date") AS "RunningTotal_Installs"
FROM
    "Adtracking"
WHERE
    "Install_Date" ILIKE '2021-06%'
GROUP BY
    1,
    2,
    3
ORDER BY
    1,
    2
```

Comment: *What I would like to achieve* Show arithmetic expression (which uses source values) which produces %_of_daily_LAT value for each output row.

Comment: We can't run your query without sample data for `ADJUST_CSV_DATA`, please supply a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain the formula required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following divides the daily installs for each Lat type by the total /sum of daily installs for each install date and finally rounds that to 2 decimal places.

```sql
ROUND("No_of_daily_installs"/(SUM("No_of_daily_installs") OVER (PARTITION BY "Install_Date")),2) AS "%_of_daily_LAT"
```

You may try the complete example:

```sql
WITH "Adtracking" (
    "Install_Date",
    "Lat_type",
    "No_of_daily_installs"
) AS (
    SELECT
        to_date("created_at") date_install,
        CASE WHEN "tracking_limited" = '1' THEN
            'Limit Ad Tracking'
        ELSE
            'Ad Tracking Enabled'
        END AS "Ad Tracking",
        count("tracking_limited") AS "number_of_occurences"
    FROM
        TEMP_DB.DATA_LAKE.ADJUST_CSV_DATA
    WHERE
        TRUE
        AND "platform" = 'mobile_app'
        AND "activity_kind" = 'install'
        AND "os_name" = 'ios'
    GROUP BY
        1,
        2
    ORDER BY
        1,
        2
)
SELECT
    "Install_Date",
    "Lat_type",
    "No_of_daily_installs",
-- modification begins
    ROUND("No_of_daily_installs"/(SUM("No_of_daily_installs") OVER (PARTITION BY "Install_Date")),2) AS "%_of_daily_LAT"
-- modification ends
    SUM("No_of_daily_installs") OVER (PARTITION BY "Lat_type" ORDER BY "Install_Date") AS "RunningTotal_Installs"
FROM
    "Adtracking"
WHERE
    "Install_Date" ILIKE '2021-06%'
GROUP BY
    1,
    2,
    3
ORDER BY
    1,
    2
```